# Installing Windows on Chromebook Pixel

Tags: windows, chromebook

I know it's not supported, but is it possible?
I just don't want to spend $1300 and end up with chrome os...
Chances are it is possible, since there are blog posts over how to install Ubuntu on it, so if Ubuntu can be installed, then windows installation should do fine as well.
Also, as far as I know, the hardware (i.e CPU architecture) supports windows just fine.
Anyone tried this before?

Comment: Your problem will most likely be lack of drivers for all hardware components, not getting Windows itself installed. Isn't there anything else with a comparable price and form factor that you can buy whose manufacturer actually supports Windows and Linux?

Comment: @Karan the specs appear to represent no driver issues that I can see. It appears to be a standard Intel i5 build...

Comment: @AthomSfere: So no issues at all with obtaining Windows drivers for the touchscreen, touchpad, webcam, audio, Wi-Fi, ...?

Comment: Hmmm I can see your point... So does this mean that the pixel doesn't use the windows-supported touchpad,webcam,audion,et devices?

Comment: Do you want to risk it?

Comment: I'm a google fanatic, so I really really want to get the pixel. Plus it's the highest resolution laptop in the world, and who doesn't want that. The only problem is the os.

Comment: I would guess the hard ware all has a Windows generic driver, and maybe even a driver from the chip maker for webcam, trackpad etc. if you could track down exactly whats in there... But thats speculation and I have no way to know without exact parts or a Pixel in front of me.

Comment: The tech specs posted on the official page look pretty standard to me, so i assume that other hardware devices are also standard. It's unlikely that Google would manufacture its own specific hardware.

Comment: One last thing to point out: If MacBooks can run windows, it's unlikely that the Pixel can't.